# SHIB token transferred away in a hack

Tags: transactions, trustwallet

As the title says I woke up and my Shib had been transferred to an address.  0xc93e79c681a565cd5525c8b8b753617107878385

Can anyone please tell me how or why this happened. If it’s a hack, why didn’t they clear me out as this was one of my smaller holdings. It makes no sense.

Comment: I have to use this answer section as I don't have the Rep to comment but there's not enough information in the question. What is the transaction hash? To answer your question generally you may have interacted with a fraudulent contract even if not recently. Even if it's something otherwise I wouldn't trust your key.

Comment: Can you share the transaction hash?

Comment: Of course, sorry do the general question not sure how to go about it. The transaction hash is: 0x66bfd70fc77a51ad42e6bf56ed12f6621fb8d03ef37374c1383593513a8d5d44